# Solr unsupported encoding ANSI

Tags: apache, solr, jetty, encode, ansi

I need to encode in **ANSI** with **post.jar** but I always get `unsupported encoding: ANSI` when I try `-Dfile.encode=ANSI`.

How can I change the default supported encoding? ( server is Jetty )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right encoding constant for ANSI in java is Cp1252.
So you have to specify:

```
-Dfile.encode=Cp1252
```